# Proof of $f(z)=(z-\lambda_{2})\cdot\cdot\cdot(z-\lambda_{m})$ is equal to zero when applied to operator $T$ with $n$ distinct eigenvalues.

Tags: proof-verification

$\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$, Dim$V=n$ and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_{1},..., \lambda_{n}$. Let $f$ be the polynomial defined by $f(z)=(z-\lambda_{2})\cdot\cdot\cdot(z-\lambda_{m})$.

Prove that $f(T)=0$

**My proof:**

First, notice that $f$ is defined by the standard factorization of a polynomial with complex coefficients.

$
\begin{align}
\longrightarrow f(T)\vec{v}&=(T\vec{v}-\lambda_{1}\vec{v})\cdot\cdot\cdot(T\vec{v}-\lambda_{n}\vec{v})\\
&=a_{o}I\vec{v} + a_{1}T\vec{v}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+a_nT^n\vec{v}\\
&=(a_{o}I + a_{1}T+\cdot\cdot\cdot+a_nT^n)\vec{v}\\
&=(T-\lambda_1I)\cdot\cdot\cdot(T-\lambda_nI)\vec{v}
\end{align}$

Isolating the last term, $(T-\lambda_nI)\vec{v}$ which is equal to $0$ by the definition of eigenvalues/eigenvectors we see that $f(T)=0$.

I am concerned with the lambdas being incorrectly placed/distributed. I'm really bad at the algebra part of linear algebra. Thanks for the check on that and anything else.

Comment: Do you really want $(z-\lambda_{2})\cdots(z-\lambda_{m})$?

Comment: Do you ask about the m? Otherwise, that is the problem statement as given to me.

Comment: Yes, the $m$. There's an $n$ in the rest of the question, not $n$. Also do you really want to start the product with $z-\lambda_1$?